# Why did the IP and port number change in Kitematic?

Tags: macos, docker

I am running Mac OS 10.10.3.

I am using Kitematic and Docker in a development environment. Yesterday I installed a container for Postgre. The mac ip and port for this container was 192.168.99.100:5432.

I shut down my system for the day.

Today, when I restarted my system, started Kitematic, and started the containner The ip and port was 192.168.99.100:32771.

Why did it change?

Comment: I added these flags to the run command for docker.  Or I should say for the command line that Kitematic provided.  Here is what the commands look like: 'docker run -d -i -t -p 5432:5432 -e DB=space_manager -e USER=space_admin -e PASS=xxXX docker.xxxx.com/postgres-db  I shut down Kitematic.  Then I restarted Kitematic and restarted the docker container.  The port number changed the mac port is now 32769

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported. Click on Settings, then ports, click on the port and you can change it.

[image: Screenshot showing changing port]

[Issue on kitematic github.](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/344)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are not designating the port when you start your container and instead it is run with the `-P` option, which assigns a random port to any exposed ports. If you use the `-p HOSTPORT:GUESTPORT` option instead of `-P` the port will be consistent.

Check out the [Expose and Run documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

Comment: what is the output of `docker ps`

Comment: Just a heads up, the link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature has not been implemented yet.
https://github.com/kitematic/kitematic/issues/164

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe kitematic supports assigning ports and only does the equivalent of the -P option of docker run.